# How to write python list containing pairs in a JSON file in a custom format?

Tags: python, json

I have a list named `name_class` containing pairs of names and labels respectively like `['2_255.png', 255], ['1_256.png', 256], ['2_257.png', 257]`. Now I want to write a json file with the following structure

```
{
    "names": [
        ["2_255.png",255],
        ["1_256.png",256],
        ["1_257.png",257]

    ]
}
```

So far my code is like below

```
with open(json_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dumps(name_class, outfile, indent=1)
```

Which produces

```
[
 [
 "2_255.png",
 255
 ],
 [
 "1_256.png",
 256
 ],
 [
 "1_257.png",
 257
 ]
]
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind each of these to a dictionary entry with name "names":

```
with open("json.json", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps({"names": name_class}, indent=1))
```

Comment: This works fine. However, my list pairs are still on different lines. Is there a way to have line consistency? like below
["2_255.png",255],
["1_256.png",256],

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan Remove the `indent=1`

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, this should work:

```
json_object = { 'names': name_class }
with open(json_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_object, outfile, indent=1)
```

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Comment: My bad, I used `json.dumps` instead of `json.dump`. Now it should work